# Dagger 2 - Bind into map of a dependent Component

Tags: android, mvvm, dagger-2, dagger, subcomponent

I would like to know if or how it is possible to contribute into a map of a parent component.

This is my setup of the parent component and its graph:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);

        AppComponent build();
    }

    ViewModelProvider.Factory plusViewModelFactory();
}

@Module
public abstract class AppModule {
    @Multibinds
    abstract Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, ViewModel> bindViewModels();

    @Binds
    abstract ViewModelProvider.Factory bindViewModelFactory(MyViewModelFactory myViewModelFactory);
}

@Singleton
public class MyViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    private final Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> creators;

    @Inject
    MyViewModelFactory(Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> creators) {
        this.creators = creators;
    }

    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
        // ... Irrelevant code
    }
}
```

Second I want each `Activity` to have a `Component` that depends on the `AppComponent`:

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {
    @Module
    static abstract class StartModule {
        @Binds
        @IntoMap
        @ViewModelKey(StartViewModel.class)
        abstract ViewModel bindStartViewModel(StartViewModel startViewModel);
    }

    @StartScope
    @Component(dependencies = AppComponent.class, modules = StartModule.class)
    interface StartComponent {
        void inject(StartActivity startActivity);
    }

    @Inject
    ViewModelProvider.Factory viewModelFactory;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        StartComponent component = DaggerStartActivity_StartComponent
                .builder()
                .appComponent(((MyApplication) getApplication()).getAppComponent())
                .build();
        component.inject(this);    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println(viewModelFactory.toString());
        // ... Irrelevant code
    }
}
```

The bound `ViewModelProvider.Factory` of the `AppComponent` is correctly injected into this `StartActivity` but obviously empty, as the `AppModule` simply doesn't bind any providers of any `ViewModel` itself. What I would like to happen though is that providers of `ViewModel`s bound later by each `Activity` are put into the same `Map` that the factory uses. Either I'm not looking at this problem from the right angle or there is a feature missing in Dagger 2 for this purpose.

Optionally I could have gone with declaring my `Activity`'s component as a subcomponent but then I lose the modularity.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? Having the same problem now

Comment: I ended up using the SubComponent-pattern.

Comment: @11m0 How did you solve this problem?